# How to add ATTR_LATEX to all babel blocks efficiently?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I recently figured out how to make my babel codes to have a border background when export as pdf.  I did it by adding the following before the BEGIN_SRC:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options  frame=single
```

This works, but is there a way to make this global for a particular org document? I have a lot of the org babel code, I didnt know you could add background before.  Now that I do, is there anyway other than going back to every single block and add the code above?

Comment: I am not super-familiar with org, but [here's a hint](https://orgmode.org/manual/Source-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html) I found in the org documentation: > In the example below, the ‘:options’ are set for Minted. Minted is a source
> code highlighting LaTeX package with many configurable options. [...].
> **To apply similar configuration options for all source blocks in a
> file**, use the **org-latex-listings-options** and **org-latex-minted-options**
> variables. I don't know how to set these variables from within your org-document, though.

Comment: You could just do a search-and-replace: search for `#+BEGIN_SRC` and replace with `#+ATTR_LATEX: :options frame=single\n#+BEGIN_SRC`.